# How to Get user input from a Text Entry Box in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

in an android website, I found an article about how to create a text entry widget that provides auto-complete suggestions. (Following is the link to the site; and it shows all the codes).

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Can anyone please tell me how I can capture the input entered by the user? For example, if the user chooses “Canada”, is there a way I can know the result in the “HelloAutoComplete.java” activity? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class HelloAutoComplete extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);       

    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("Canada")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result Canada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  //Does not get an out put when I select Canada.
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });

}  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textView.getText();

textView.getText().toString(); // If you need an actual String
```

Currently your code does not hook up the listener to the text view.

You need to either (a) use an immediate listener:

```
textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals("Canada")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result Canada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
});
```

Or (b) if you want to use the activity as the listener (I wouldn't) have it implement the interface and set the `itemSelectedListener` to this. But yuck.

---

To set the selected text into another text element, a few changes must be made. First, the layout must now include the autocomplete "component", and the additional text view. We set the "parent" layout to vertical orientation, create a new horizontal layout for the autoselect stuff, and add a new text view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              a:orientation="vertical"
              a:layout_width="fill_parent"
              a:layout_height="wrap_content"
              a:padding="5dp">

  <LinearLayout a:orientation="horizontal"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView a:layout_width="wrap_content"
              a:layout_height="wrap_content"
              a:text="Country"/>

    <AutoCompleteTextView a:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
                          a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          a:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView a:id="@+id/selected_country"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity gets a new `TextView` instance property, which I'm calling `selectedCountry`. I'm not showing its declaration. The `onCreate` method looks it up by ID, and the select listener just updates it.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Text view for selected country.
    selectedCountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_country);

    textView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            selectedCountry.setText(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) { }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. That method works for getting user’s input. But I am not sure how to use it with “if, else,” statements. I have edited my previous question with code, please look in to it and tell me how correct it. Thanks a lot for you time.

Comment: @NewGuy See updated answer, same as dmon's, which I've upvoted since it's correct (delta the 1.5/1.6 issue). The above code works as-is for me.

Comment: @Dave Newton I have changed my program the way you explained it, but it still doesn't show any output after I select Canada. should the code you have provided be nested inside "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" ? if I try to declare it outside as another function, it gives me error. I have updated my original question above, please let me know what I should change in it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NewGuy Yes, it should be part of the `onCreate` method. Not sure what else to tell you; the toast should show up as soon as you arrow over `Canada`--it does for me ([image](http://imgur.com/hpbxt)).

Comment: Thanks a lot; it does work when I go through with arrows. I was using the mouse to select Canada and it didn't work that way. Thanks for all your help and now the problem is solved. I have one last question. Is there any other way to display the text "Result Canada" without using Toast.makeText(...). This will only show my text for a small period of time. I would like the "Result Canada" output to stay in there for a long time (just like a text filed). Please let me know if you know a way to do that?

Comment: @NewGuy You'd need to create an additional `TextView` and set its content using `setText()` on the select event. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to set an "item selected listener" which will notify you when the user has picked something from the available entries. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29). With this you can get the item from the adapter that they picked (and, conversely, whatever you defined for that item's text).

Example:

```
textView.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View selectedView, 
         int selectedPosition, long selectedId) {
         //do stuff here     
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I did it the way you explained it. but it still doesn't print any output when I select "Canada". can you please look in to my updated original question and see if I did something wrong there? It does not let me put two @Override things as you shows in your example though. Thanks.

Comment: @NewGuy The `@Override` annotation just means that dmon is compiling using 1.6+, where `@Override` can be applied to interface methods (< 1.6 it applied exclusively to overridden class methods).

Comment: Seems fine, could you use a toast or Log to see if the code is reaching that spot?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
textView.getText().toString();
```

Then display it through Toast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it didn't work either. it would show a value at the start of the program and nothing else after that.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

textView.getText().toString()